# php: get variable type hint using reflection

Tags: php, class, reflection, types

```
class Expense {

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;
}
```

I would like to obtain the type hint of a variable in my class, using reflection, because the default value is null.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
class Expense {

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;
}

$refClass = new ReflectionClass('Expense');
foreach ($refClass->getProperties() as $refProperty) {
    if (preg_match('/@var\s+([^\s]+)/', $refProperty->getDocComment(), $matches)) {
        list(, $type) = $matches;
        var_dump($type);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
string(3) "int"
```

Answer (score 5):

For PHP 7.4

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionProperty('className', 'propertyName');
echo $reflection->getType()->getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Obtain the complete Docblock:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionProperty('Expense', 'id');

$doc = $reflection->getDocComment();
```

Answer (score 3):

If PHPDoc comments prove to be missing or unreliable, you can type hint all the properties of a class *provided they have a matching getter*.

```
public function getClassPropertiesType(string $className): array {
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($className);

    $reflectionProperties = $reflectionClass->getProperties();
    $properties = [];
    foreach ($reflectionProperties as $reflectionProperty) {
        $properties[] = $reflectionProperty->getName();
    }

    $methods = $reflectionClass->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
    $results = [];

    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        foreach ($methods as $method) {
            // get only methods that have 0 parameter and start with 'get'
            if ($method->getNumberOfParameters() === 0 && 
                  strpos($method->getName(),'get') !== false && 
                  stripos($method->getName(), $property) !== false) {

                $results[$property] = (string)$method->getReturnType();
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Logically, there should be only one getter for each property of the class.

If I dump the properties of some class:

```
  0 => "id"
  1 => "email"
  2 => "password"
  3 => "firstName"
  4 => "lastName"
  5 => "gender"
  6 => "position"
  7 => "isActive"
  9 => "dateEmployedFrom"
  10 => "dateEmployedTo"
  11 => "dateOfBirth"
  12 => "ssn"
  13 => "mobilePhone"
  14 => "homePhone"
  15 => "address"
  16 => "zipCode"
  17 => "city"
  18 => "country"
```

This is what you get:

```
  "id" => "int"
  "email" => "string"
  "password" => "string"
  "firstName" => "string"
  "lastName" => "string"
  "gender" => "bool"
  "position" => "string"
  "isActive" => "bool"
  "dateEmployedFrom" => "DateTimeInterface"
  "dateEmployedTo" => "DateTimeInterface"
  "dateOfBirth" => "DateTimeInterface"
  "ssn" => "string"
  "mobilePhone" => "string"
  "homePhone" => "string"
  "address" => "string"
  "zipCode" => "string"
  "city" => "string"
  "country" => "string"
```

*Limitations + workaround*

If a property doesn't have any getter, you can start looking for setters (or methods that start with 'add', 'is', 'remove'), *provided the method's arguments are type hinted*. *You could also include private properties in your search*  `$methods = $reflectionClass->getMethods(); // no filter`

I suggest expanding like this, before returning:

```
        $missingProperties = array_diff_key(array_flip($properties), $results);

        if (!empty($missingProperties)) { // some properties are missing

            foreach ($missingProperties as $missingProperty => $val) {
                // get only methods that have 1 parameter and start with 'set'
                if ($method->getNumberOfParameters() === 1 && strpos($method->getName(), 'set') !== false) { 
                    $parameters = $method->getParameters();

                    // if not already in results, and parameter is required 
                    // and is a class property
                    if(!array_key_exists($parameters[0]->getName(), $results) &&
                                !$parameters[0]->isOptional() && 
                                in_array($parameters[0]->getName(), $properties, true)) {

                        $string = $parameters[0]->__toString();

                        $string = substr($string, strlen('Parameter #0 [ <required> '));
                        $pos = strpos($string, ' '); // get first space after type
                        $string = substr($string, 0, $pos); // get type

                        $results[$parameters[0]->getName()] = $string;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Of course, this is not 100% bulletproof, but hopefully it will help. :-)

Last: PHP 7.4 introduces [ReflectionParameter::getType](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.gettype.php) 
So, you could drop the above string manipulation and just write:

```
                $type = $parameters[0]->getType();
                $results[$parameters[0]->getName()] = $type->__toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a warning - PHP accelerators and some libraries themselves (i.e. symfony core) strip comments, quite often on the *second* run.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I proposed a solution using reflection

Comment: Well, it might have changed in the last 8 years, didn't keep up to date with PHP.

Comment: The joys of Unity3D? - Sure seems great :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ReflectionDocBlock](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/ReflectionDocBlock).

Installation

```
composer require phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock
```

Usage:

```
$factory  = \phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlockFactory::createInstance();

$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(MyClass::class);
$property = $reflectionClass->getProperty('foo');

$docBlock = $factory->create($property->getDocComment());

//it returns an array, as a property might declare many types
//for example @var int|string|null
$types = $docBlock->getTagsByName('var')[0]->getType()
```

See the reference of [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and [ReflectionProperty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php)

Answer (score -1):

In PHP7.4

```php
    public function getKeysAndTypes(): array
    {
        $return = [];
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass(static::class);
        foreach ($reflectionClass->getProperties() as $reflectionProperty) {
            if ($reflectionProperty->isPublic()) {
                $return[$reflectionProperty->getName()] = $reflectionProperty->getType()->getName();
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
```